# Передать значение которое содержит append в файл

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача, такова что я пытаюсь передать полученное значение в данном случае это числа 1 1 1, значения данные содержит эта строчка в коде `$('#res').append(' ');` далее я пытаюсь передать это значение в функцию которая принимает параметры и сохраняет данное значение в файл, строчка

```
var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + $('#res').append(' ');
```

как только я вставил строчку `$('#res').append(' ')` то в файл записывается следующее [objectObject], да я делаю ошибку когда пытаюсь писать на js и на jquery в одном месте. Подскажите как сделать чтобы значения 1 1 1 которая содержит эта строчка `$('#res').append(' ')` попадали в файл

```
function recalculate(){

    $('#res').text('');
    var sum = 0;
    $('div').each(function(){
        var selectVal = $('select',this).val();

        $('#res').append(selectVal);
        if($(this).index() < $('div').length - 1){
            $('#res').append(' '); //содержит значения 1 1 1
        }
        sum +=selectVal * 1;
    });
    $('#res').append('<p>Согласовано: ' + sum + ' </p>');
    document.getElementById('tfa_src_data').onclick = function() {                  
                        var csv = JSON.stringify(localStorage['savedCoords']);
                        var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' 
                                       + $('#res').append(' ');
                        this.href = csvData;
                        this.target = '_blank';
                        this.download = 'filename.txt';


}};
```

Comment: что за элемент `#res`?

Comment: @Grundy . в html коде это <span id="res"></span>, сюда выводится результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) возвращает объект jQuery, поэтому при приведении его к строке получается `[object Object]`

Для того, чтобы получить текст/html из элемента span, можно воспользоваться методами [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)/[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

В итоге строка может выглядеть так:

```
var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + $('#res').append(' ').text();
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, теперь запись происходит корректно.